# Angular2, bind().toClass()

Tags: dependency-injection, angular2-directives

Could some help me explan why does

> bind(UserService).toClass(UserService)

mean in Angular2?

tnx
miha

P.s. the whole code goes like this:

```
export var userServiceInjectables: Array<any> = [       bind(UserService).toClass(UserService)
];
```

Comment: Some related questions in my mind are:

1. Are we exporting a variable here? Do we use the keyword export with var userServiceInjectables because we might inject this variable as dependency?

2. Why are we making an array?

3. The type of the array is <any>, so what do we have now inside the array?

4. Why are we passing UserService to both bind() and toClass()?

Answer (score -2):

See [Angular2 documentation](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/angular2/2.0.0-alpha.29/angular2.angular2/Binding/toClass.html). You simply bind the UserService alias to the UserService implementation, so you can inject UserService class as UserService.